# Outer and Inner Glow with transparent WPF Buttons

Tags: wpf, button, styles

I want my WPF `Button` to get an outer glow effect when the mouse hovers over it. How can I achieve this when the `Button` is transparent?

When I use a `BitmapEffect` such as a `DropShadow` or `OuterGlow` the glow appears at the inside of the `Button` as well because it is transparent. But I want the glow to be only at the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the outer glow to a border?

```
<Border Width="100" Height="100" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
    <Border.BitmapEffect>
        <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="Red" GlowSize="3" Opacity="1" />
    </Border.BitmapEffect>
</Border>
```